# Xamarin android save string to strings.xml

Tags: c#, android, xml, string, xamarin

Let's say I have and `EditText` in my Xamarin.Android app. I want to take the text from it and save it as a string in the Strings.xml . How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strings.xml` cannot be modified programmatically. They are **constant strings**.

If you need to save a string & preserve it, simplest way is to use **SharedPreferences** to store value as key-value pairs. Try

```
ISharedPreferences sharedprefs = GetSharedPreferences("prefs_file", FileCreationMode.Private);
sharedprefs.Edit().PutString("keyName","value").Commit();
```

You can retrieve the string using "keyName" like

```
 ISharedPreferences sharedprefs = GetSharedPreferences("prefs_file", FileCreationMode.Private);
 String str = sharedprefs.GetString("keyName", null);
```

Comment: So if I were to make a different xml file in, say, the Assets folder i wouldn't be able to modify that at all?

Comment: @Reaper9806 No. Your assets and resources get compiled into the application. You can only access them through code.